# I cannot acces modelmap values in my JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I was refactoring my code and ended up deleting a bean altogether. ModelMap values were getting passed correctly and displayed on my JSP page with the presence of that bean. Now however, I am pulling data directly from the database, but I cannot access those values on my JSP page even though the data is getting read correctly.

I have something like:-

```
public String viewData(@ModelAttribute("") ModelMap model) {
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    Statement statement = null;
    try{
          Class.forName(driver);
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing1234","root","root");
          statement = conn.createStatement();
          String sql = "SELECT * FROM  testdata";
           rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
          while (rs.next()) {
          model.addAttribute("test", rs.getString(1));
          model.addAttribute("test1", rs.getString(2));
          model.addAttribute("test2", rs.getString(3));
          model.addAttribute("test3", rs.getString(4));
          model.addAttribute("test4" ,rs.getDate(5));
            }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }finally {

     try {
         if (rs != null) {
             rs.close();
         }
         if (statement != null) {
             statement.close();
         }
         if (conn!= null) {
             conn.close();
         }
     } catch (SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 } 
    return "jsppage";
}
```

However, in my JSP page when I try accessing ${test}, I get an empty string. Would there be any alternate way around this, so that I can display the data on my JSP page?

Comment: Don't show us something like. Show us _exactly_ what's up. That should work fine. Show us how you get from setting the model attribute to rendering (forwarding) the JSP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring handles handler method arguments with the `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` interface. The implementation that handles `@ModelAttribute`, `ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor`, has higher priority (is registered before) the implementation that handles `ModelMap`, `MapMethodProcessor`.

What this means is that Spring will create a `ModelMap` object and put it into the `Model` with key `""`. You can access that attribute with an empty key from your JSP and access its elements through it (the nested attributes you add from the `ResultSet`).

The best solution IMO is to get rid of the `@ModelAttribute` annotation from your method parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to remove the annotation @ModelAttribute("").

By the way, you should reconsider moving the business and data access logic to a service and DAO layer.